# jQuery alter element if has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, this

I have a simple but troublesome issue. I have a `<select>` field and some `<div>`s with `checkbox` groups. When the value of the `<select>` field is changed, I want to check the `<div>`s and if they have the class `hidden` then I want to uncheck all their checkboxes.

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">some value 1</option>
  <option value="2">some value 2</option>
</select>

<div id="skills-container-1" class="skills-container hidden"> 
  <fieldset id="P2_SKILLS_1" class="checkbox_group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_v16" value="2033"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_v17" value="2034"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_v18" value="2035"><br>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="skills-container-2" class="skills-container hidden"> 
  <fieldset id="P2_SKILLS_2" class="checkbox_group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_v19" value="2036"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_v20" value="2037"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_v21" value="2038"><br>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

In javascript, in document ready function, at the `.change` event of the `<select>` field I do the following:

```
if ($('.skills-container').hasClass('hidden')) {
 $(this).find('input').removeAttr('checked');
}
```

and apparently it doesn't work. I am not sure if I am using the **`this`** item correctly. Propably `this` refers to the `<select>` element and not the `<div>` that has the class `hidden`.
Any thoughts to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple one-liner will do that...

```
$("div.skills-container.hidden input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
```

It finds all the checkboxes inside divs with the classes `.skills-container` and `.hidden` and sets the property `checked` to false.

Just put that inside your change event :)

**Edit:**
As suggested by Alnitak, you could narrow the selection down even further by only selecting the checkboxes that are currently checked, rather than setting them to unchecked regardless.  This may or may not have an impact on performance, but it's definitely worth checking if you have a lot of checkboxes that could be affected by this.

```
$("div.skills-container.hidden input:checkbox:checked").prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: @eyetea do also take note of this answer's (correct) use of `.prop('checked', false)` instead of `.removeAttr` to update the checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the speedoflight anwser! Works fine!

Comment: you _might_ consider adding a `:checked` qualifier to the selector.

Comment: @Alnitak Good point.  If we're not talking about a LOT of checkboxes then it probably wouldn't make any difference and I'd (personally) rather a shorter selector, but a performance test would be needed to say whether it's quicker to set the property on all of them, or check the property on all of them and then just set it on some.  My inner OCD sees jsperf in my near future ;)

Comment: The checkboxes are not more than 200

Comment: @eyetea It probably won't be an issue then, but I'll include the suggestion from Alnitak in the answer so you can try it and see for yourself.

Comment: @Archer FWIW, I would _expect_ the `:checked` version to be marginally faster in modern browsers that support `querySelectorAll`.  It may well be slower if jQuery has to invoke sizzle to do its work for it.

Answer (score 2):

*edit* — use Archer's superior answer!

You'll need to check each "skills container" separately:

```
$('.skills-container').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('hidden'))
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false);
});
```

When you're asking questions with APIs like `.hasClass()`, you only get an answer for the first matched element. By iterating with `.each()` you can perform the operation separately on each one.

Comment: why separately?  @Archer's answer looks fine to me.

Comment: @Alnitak yes it's better! :)

Comment: You are of course correct that `.hasClass` will only work on one element at a time, but why bother with `.hasClass` when a selector will do all of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser! @Archer's anwser works fine for me :)

Comment: @eyetea it's not my answer - I was just commenting

Comment: @Alnitak sorry, I meant Archer, both your names start with 'A' and I did a wrong autocomplete :P

Answer (score 0):

Find all the `checked` items and make it unchecked

```
 $('.skills-container.hidden').find(':checked').prop('checked',false):
```

Comment: sometimes it's just easier to uncheck everything than to make jQuery work harder finding the elements you want.  The single selector in Archer's answer will be more efficient on modern browsers that using a selector followed by `.find()`.  The exception is for jQuery pseudo-selectors, where it's best to separate out standard CSS selectors.